# How to access props.children in a class component (not functional component) in ReactJS 18?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to convert some ReactJS code that was written in a much older version (I think 14 or 16) to 18, and the code uses props.children multiple times, which was removed in the newer versions of ReactJS. I've found plenty of tutorials for fixing this, **but I can only find ones that refer to functional components, not classes.**

```
export class SystemStatusContainer extends React.Component<
  {},
  {
    status: systemStatuses;
    pollStatus: boolean;
  }
  > {
  state = {
    status: systemStatuses.online,
    pollStatus: true,
  };

  timer: NodeJS.Timeout;
.
.
.
render() {
    const { status } = this.state;

    if (status === systemStatuses.offline) {
      return <SystemUnavailableModal />;
    } else if (status === systemStatuses.update) {
      return <SystemStatusModal />;
    } else {
      return this.props.children;
    }
  }
```

How do I convert the bottom line, this.props.children, to work in the ReactJS 18? All the methods I found online involve passing children directly into the component, but this only works if it's a functional component, not a class (from what I can tell).

**NOTE:** This code is not mine, and because of this, I'm trying to minimize the changes as much as possible. If there are problems in the code unrelated to this question, please do not bring them up unless they will directly impact the problem with this.props.children.

Comment: Can you point the reference where you found out that props.children is removed from class components? If you are converting old version the the newest, then why you don't replace class components with functional ones, as it is the standard now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code totally works on runtime. This is just a typescript error.

React did not remove the `this.props.children`, but you have an error on the previous code because the first argument of `React.Component` is the type of the props. In there, you didn't define any prop, not even the children. So the typescript compiler warns you: `Property 'children' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'.ts(2339)`

If you define the type properly, the error is gone.

```
export class SystemStatusContainer extends React.Component<
  { children: React.ReactNode },
...
```

Take a look at [this playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-platform-hycgwt?file=/src/App.tsx).

You can specify the children as a named prop or inside the tag:

```
  <SystemStatusContainer> This is children </SystemStatusContainer>
  <SystemStatusContainer children="This is children too!" />
```

What changed from React 17 to React 18 are the typings. In react 17, [the type Component did include children in the props](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/04a94ba88f0eac866e87654d001bf5862166f62c/types/react/v17/index.d.ts#L496).

```
class Component {
    ...
    readonly props: Readonly<P> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode | undefined }>;
}
```

[In the typings for React 18](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/04a94ba88f0eac866e87654d001bf5862166f62c/types/react/index.d.ts#L523), props is just a readonly object:

```
class Component {
    ...
    readonly props: Readonly<P>;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that seems to be it, thanks. I wasn't sure about all of the changes made in react and everytime I searched props.children, I just got stack overflow questions about it being removed or not accessible anymore, but maybe that's only for functional components.

Comment: Well spotted! Please update the answer to show what the component's props declaration should look like **in** the answer, not just linked. Answers must stand alone, they can't rely on off-site content.

Answer (score 0):

The change in React 18 was to remove `children` from the *type* of props by default (both in `Component` and in the `React.FunctionComponent` [aka `React.FC`] type optionally used by function components). It was removed is that not all components should have children (consider a component that ends up rendering just a void element like `<br/>`).

If your component has children, it will have a `children` prop containing those children. So what we have to do is ensure the type of your component's props says that.

To make that code work again, declare `children` in the props type (the first type argument to `Component`). React provides a utility type, `PropsWithChildren`, that will add `children` to a props type. React defines `PropsWithChildren` like this:

```typescript
export type PropsWithChildren<P = unknown> = P & {
    children?: ReactNode | undefined;
};
```

So we'd use it on your empty props object type:

```typescript
export class SystemStatusContainer extends React.Component<
  PropsWithChildren<{}>, // <=======================
  {
    status: systemStatuses;
    pollStatus: boolean;
  }
  > {
  state = {
    status: systemStatuses.online,
    pollStatus: true,
  };
  // ...
```

Here's a very basic example ([on the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQuCA7AphmAaOABSgjAGcB1YGAC2RuABsATKHOAXzgDMSQ4ARGwCGAYxgCA3AChpoxsLJk4AUQAew8IyxwsamDmbLU6bLgA8xUpWp0GLNhnMIOAPgIvXiaXF9xHzFhQABQAlN5+kf5YMACuUBhwtMBkAHRgJOSpovasODKRHNIcQA)):

```typescript
import { Component, PropsWithChildren } from "react";

class Example extends Component<PropsWithChildren<{}>, {}> {
    render() {
        return this.props.children;
    }
}
```